# The table column disappeared after restoration ( Postgresql )

Tags: database, postgresql

In my database, I hava a table collection and multiple columns. I did backup in my datatbase using pg_dump : pg_dump dspace > bkp_dspace_20160229.sql
I did the restore as follows: 
psql –d dspace –f bkp_dspace_20160229.sql
My tabke collection not appear some columns. Why ?

Comment: You'll need to provide some actual information I'm afraid. Look in your backup file and find the relevant CREATE TABLE - check the column is mentioned. Then, check the output when you restore and see if there are any errors. If you still can't see what is happening, try trimming down the backup file (`pg_dump --schema-only` could be useful) or even trimming the backup by hand.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I deleted the database and did the restore again. thank you.